# How to use index in the file name

Tags: c

This is probably trivial question. I am not a professional programmer, I am rather a mathematician who is doing some numerical experiment using C. I would like the output of my 
experiment to be written in different files for different values of a parameter. MWE should do something like this. Crate a file pointer indexed by i. Open a file named file[i]. Write 
i into that file and then close it. The code below obviously doesn't compile. Is such a construction even possible?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i;

int 
main()
{
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                FILE *f(i);
                f(i)=fopen("file"[i],"w");
                fprintf(f(i),"%d \n", i);
                fclose(f(i));  
        }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** I got several decent answers but can somebody help to fix the sprintf problem. Namely on OpenBSD which I use sprintf is not recommended. So I get this message

```
$ gcc test.c
/tmp//ccN31aTv.o(.text+0x41): In function `main':
: warning: sprintf() is often misused, please use snprintf()
```

When I replace sprintf with snprintf I get all sorts of warnings

```
$ gcc test.c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:9: warning: passing argument 2 of 'snprintf' makes integer from pointer without a cast
test.c:9: warning: passing argument 3 of 'snprintf' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

That doesn't look like a great quality code to me.

**Final Solution:** I just want to document final solution. ProPolice and systrace are happy with this code on OpenBSD. Thanks to everyone who helped!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i;

char buf[20];

int
main()
{
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "filename%d", i);
                FILE *f = fopen( buf, "w");
                fprintf(f,"%d \n", i);
                fclose(f);
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean write to file1, file2, file3, etc... or do you want to write to a specific offset?

Comment: @Jesus Ramos file1, file2,file3 would be OK. Specific offset would be nice.

Comment: Check out the `fseek` call for specific offsets and the answer below for specific filename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, use snprintf:

```
char buf[PATH_MAX];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "file%d", i);
```

If you use linux, there is a useful GNU extension:

```
char *name;
asprintf(&name. "file%d", i);
```

You need to remember to free(name) after use.

Note that your syntax `FILE *f(i);` is not valid though.

If you need to declare an array of FILE * of 10 elements do:

```
FILE *array[10];
```

then use it like that:

```
array[i] = fopen(filename, "W");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sprintf` to generate the filename.

```
char buf[80];
sprintf(buf,"file%d", i);
fopen(buf,"w");
```

Array syntax in C uses square brackets `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just build a string up with `sprintf`.  Make sure your buffer is large enough:

```
char filename[20];
sprintf( filename, "file%d", i );
```

Then you can open it like this:

```
FILE *f = fopen( filename, "w");
...
fclose(f);
```

No need to use an array (if that's what you were trying to do with `f(i)`), because you're only keeping one file open at a time.

If you want your files to be text-sortable, you might want `file001`, `file002` etc...  You can use `%03d` instead of `%d` to 0-pad to 3 digits.

Comment: same issues with using sprintf instead of snprintf as enrmarc's answer.

Comment: It's pretty pedantic to use `snprintf` in this case.  We know the maximum number of digits used by an integer.  It only offers vague protection against you coming in later and deciding you want a huge file prefix.  By all means, use `snprintf` as common practice, but for such a simple throwaway string-building exercise, I think you're splitting hairs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      char filename[64];
      sprintf(filename, "file%d", i);    
      FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
      fprintf(fp, "%d\n", i);
      fclose(fp);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Your code is almost ok. Some observations:

- Use `sprintf` to create the name of the file. In C there is not a concatenate operator of strings.
- You don't need to create an array of file pointers.
- And of course, this may be improved: handling the size of the filename, padding the numbers, etc.

Comment: I just compiled. It works as desired. However, I use OpenBSD with ProPolice enabled and all sorts of other goodies. I get the warning $ gcc mama.c
/tmp//cchhwGg1.o(.text+0x41): In function `main':
: warning: sprintf() is often misused, please use snprintf()   When I replace put snprintf I get a slue of warnings $ gcc mama.c
mama.c: In function 'main':
mama.c:9: warning: passing argument 2 of 'snprintf' makes integer from pointer without a cast
mama.c:9: warning: passing argument 3 of 'snprintf' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: You should ignore that warning.  `snprintf` does not replace `sprintf`, you can't just change one to the other.  Not everything in C programming, when you're writing your own experimental code for your own purposes, has to be done according to someone else's idea of "perfectly secure" C.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac Of course, my snippet code is just a "toy".